# Event after autocomplete is filled Asp.net C# or javascript/html,

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Trying to get an event to fire (and handle it in a c# method on the page aspx.cs file) after the autocomplete fills out the textbox and password, so that I can make it automatically log in. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why not try it and see if it is possible. What stop you ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is autofill is handled differently by different browsers. Some dispatch the change event, some don't. So it is almost impossible to hook onto an event which is triggered when browser autocompletes an input field.

You best options are to either disable autocomplete for a form using autocomplete="off" in your form or poll at regular interval to see if its filled.

Source : http://avernet.blogspot.in/2010/11/autocomplete-and-javascript-change.html